# Change background color of action bar Android

Tags: java, android, xml

My background color is `#139f93` in RelativeLayout. I want to use the same color in the Actionbar.

[image: screenshot]

My **Java code**:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

What I have in **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<activity
        android:name=".book1"
        android:label="Book one"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

Any suggestions to do that?

Thanks

Comment: you can change it using by applying style.in style.xml add your custom style

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

Comment: I think you should use toolbar instead of action bar now.

Answer (score 0):

Customize your theme in your styles.xml.

Simply add the below code inside your `<style>` tag.

```
<item name="colorPrimary">#YOUR_COLOR_CODE</item>
```

For more styling options see [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I changed actionbar background color.

1) **res/values/drawable.xml**

```
<resources>
    <drawable name="actionbar_background">#139f93</drawable> //color
</resources>
```

2) **res/values>themes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
        parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
        parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

3) **manifests/AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xBDBDBD));